# How to identify the objects of a list with >1 rows in R?

Tags: r, list, object, data-manipulation

I'd like to know how to identify  the objects of a `list` with `>1 rows` in `R`?

as example let's say we have the following `list`:

```
 c = 6:10
 d = 1:5
 f = 11:15

output <- list(var1 = rbind(c,d,f), var2 = c, var3 = rbind(d,f))
output

$var1
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
c    6    7    8    9   10
d    1    2    3    4    5
f   11   12   13   14   15

$var2
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

$var3
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
d    1    2    3    4    5
f   11   12   13   14   15
```

The expected is to have a file either list or provide the name of `object` with `> 1` `row` as following:

```
output2
 $var1
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
c    6    7    8    9   10
d    1    2    3    4    5
f   11   12   13   14   15

$var3
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
d    1    2    3    4    5
f   11   12   13   14   15
```

or

```
output2 
[1] var1, var3
```

Thanks in advance for your help with explanations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `sapply`, `dim`, isTRUE, and `[` in base R:

```
output[sapply(output, function(i) isTRUE(dim(i)[1] > 1))]
$var1
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
c    6    7    8    9   10
d    1    2    3    4    5
f   11   12   13   14   15

$var3
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
d    1    2    3    4    5
f   11   12   13   14   15
```

`sapply` runs through each object and checks if the row dimension, first element of `dim`, is greater than 1. However, as vectors and some other objects (eg, lists) do not have a dimension attribute, this check returns `logical(0)`. To coerce a FALSE out of this, we wrap the output in `isTRUE`. The logical vector resulting from `sapply` is used to subset the list.

Comment: @Imo   Very smart! Thank you for the explanation ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea:

```
c = t(6:10)
d = t(1:5)
f = t(11:15)

output <- list(var1 = rbind(c,d,f), var2 = c, var3 = rbind(d,f))
output

nrow(as.data.frame(output[1]))>1
nrow(as.data.frame(output[2]))>1
nrow(as.data.frame(output[3]))>1

f <- function(x) nrow(as.data.frame(x))>1
sapply(output, f)
which(sapply(output, f))
```

I think you need to take the transpose function t() of the original vectors here to ensure that they are treated as one row with many columns, rather than many columns with one row.

Answer (score 1):

There are likely many ways to do this, but this should work:

`output2 <- names(which(unlist(purrr::map(output, ~nrow(.x)>1))==TRUE))`

Comment: Probably you need to revise your answer , cause the result of your script is not want is expected ;)

Comment: oh that's strange when I run it mine outputs`"var1" "var3"` what does it output for you?

Comment: I get all three "vars"!

Comment: if you define `c`, `d`, and `f` as you did in the original question, that should not happen, but if you define it as Green Stone did in their example, then that would happen. I've updated it to work either way.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution with `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)    
keep(output, ~ (nrow(.) %||% 1) > 1)
```

NULLs may appear (and do appear in your example) when we apply `nrow` to a 1-dimensional objects. So this `%||% 1` is here to replace NULLs with 1.

Or a bit more like @lmo's approach:

```
keep(output, ~ isTRUE(nrow(.) > 1))
```